# i have Lower Triangular Matrix issue my code is working but not what i want

Tags: java, 2d

I have written the following code for which I need help on this.

public class JavaApplication11 {

```
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           int m[][]=new int[5][5];
       int i,k,row=5,col=5,count=0;
       for(i=0;i<row;i++){
       for(k=0;k<col;k++){
       count=count+1;
       m[i][k]=count;}}
       for(i=0;i<row;i++){
       for(k=0;k<col;k++)

                if(i>=k)
       System.out.print(m[i][k]+" ");
         else

                {
                    System.out.print("0"+" ");
                }

       System.out.println();
}
}}
```

The following is the output.

```
1 0 0 0 0

2 3 0 0 0

4 5 6 0 0

7 8 9 10 0
```

(i expect like this)

```
11 12 13 14 15 

1 0 0 0 0 

6 7 0 0 0 

11 12 13 0 0 

16 17 18 19 0
```

21 22 23 24 25 (this is my output)

Answer (score 0):

A small change

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int m[][] = new int[5][5];
    int i, k, row = 5, col = 5, count = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < col; k++) {
            if (k <= i)
                m[i][k] = ++count;
            else
                m[i][k] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (k = 0; k < col; k++)
                System.out.print(m[i][k] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```